# How to remove rows from a dataframe that have overlapping start and end dates in R

Tags: r

I would like to remove products from a dataframe that have overlapping start and end dates to avoid duplicates in a subsequent step.

Example data:

```
library(dplyr)

d <-
  bind_rows(
    data.frame(product = 1, 
               start_date = as.Date("2016-01-01"), 
               end_date = as.Date("2016-01-10"), 
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
    data.frame(product = 1, 
               start_date = as.Date("2016-01-02"), 
               end_date = as.Date("2016-01-04"), 
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
    data.frame(product = 1, 
               start_date = as.Date("2016-01-05"), 
               end_date = as.Date("2016-06-09"), 
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
    data.frame(product = 2, 
               start_date = as.Date("2016-01-03"), 
               end_date = as.Date("2016-01-07"), 
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE)  
    )

  product start_date   end_date
1       1 2016-01-01 2016-01-10
2       1 2016-01-02 2016-01-04
3       1 2016-01-05 2016-06-09
4       2 2016-01-03 2016-01-07
```

From this example I would like to remove rows 2 and 3 because of the overlaps.

I've used the lag function to remove overlaps that are next to each other:

```
d_cleaned <-
  d %>%
  arrange(product, start_date, end_date) %>%
  mutate(overlapping = product == lag(product) & start_date <= lag(end_date) & end_date >= lag(start_date)) %>% # define overlaps
  mutate(overlapping = ifelse(is.na(overlapping), FALSE, overlapping)) %>% # dont delete the first row
  filter(overlapping == FALSE) %>% # remove overlaps
  select(-overlapping)

  product start_date   end_date
1       1 2016-01-01 2016-01-10
2       1 2016-01-05 2016-06-09
3       2 2016-01-03 2016-01-07
```

As can be seen above this step removes overlaps on consecutive rows but not all.

I can solve this with a loop, but I was hoping that someone might be able to suggest a non-looping solution as the dataframe is quite large and each step takes a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `non-equi` joins from the current development version of `data.table`, v1.9.7:

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.7+
setDT(d) # convert 'd' to a data.table by reference
idx = d[d, on=.(product, end_date>=start_date, start_date<=end_date), mult="first", which=TRUE]
d[idx == seq_len(.N)] # .N contains the number of rows = nrow(d)
#    product start_date   end_date
# 1:       1 2016-01-01 2016-01-10
# 2:       1 2016-06-10 2016-06-12
# 3:       2 2016-01-03 2016-01-07
```

For each row in `d` (the one inside the square bracket), we find *any* kind of overlap with `d` (on the outside), i.e., a self-join, based on the condition provided to the `on` argument, and we extract the *index* of the *first* overlap (because `which=TRUE` and `mult="first"`).

If and only if the first overlap is with itself, we return them. We discard all other intervals.

To install devel version, see installation instructions [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation).

---

Here's a benchmark on slightly more rows (the data is not by any means *large*):

```
set.seed(1L)
require(data.table) # v1.9.7+
dates = as.Date(sample(16000:17000, 1e5, TRUE), origin="1970-01-01")
dt = data.table(product=sample(100, 1e5, TRUE), 
                start_date = sample(dates, 1e5, TRUE), 
                end_date = sample(dates, 1e5, TRUE))
dt[, `:=`(start_date = pmin(start_date, end_date), 
          end_date   = pmax(start_date, end_date))]

system.time({
    idx = dt[dt, on=.(product, end_date>=start_date, start_date<=end_date), mult="first", which=TRUE, verbose=TRUE]
    ans = dt[idx == seq_len(.N)] # .N contains the number of rows = nrow(d)
})
# Non-equi join operators detected ... 
#   forder took ... 0.01 secs
#   Generating group lengths ... done in 0 secs
#   Generating non-equi group ids ... done in 0.041 secs
#   Recomputing forder with non-equi ids ... done in 0.005 secs
#   Found 178 non-equi group(s) ...
# Starting bmerge ...done in 2.359 secs

#    user  system elapsed 
#   2.402   0.011   2.421 

head(ans)
#    product start_date   end_date
# 1:      71 2015-12-04 2016-03-22
# 2:      71 2014-04-12 2015-05-01
# 3:      32 2013-11-23 2015-03-18
# 4:      56 2014-07-29 2015-12-26
# 5:      88 2015-03-08 2015-03-21
# 6:      69 2014-10-31 2015-07-05

nrow(ans)
# [1] 186
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following will work

```
d <- cbind(ID=1:nrow(d),d)
d_cleaned <- d[rep(1:nrow(d), times=nrow(d)),] %>%         ## 1
  setNames(.,paste0(names(.),"_other")) %>%                ## 2
  bind_cols(d[rep(1:nrow(d), each=nrow(d)),], .) %>%       ## 3
  arrange(product,start_date,end_date) %>%                 ## 4
  filter(product == product_other) %>%                     ## 5
  mutate(overlapping = ID_other < ID &
           start_date <= end_date_other & 
           end_date >= start_date_other) %>%               ## 6
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(all(overlapping==FALSE)) %>%                      ## 7
  ungroup() %>%
  select(product,start_date,end_date) %>%
  distinct())

print(d_cleaned)
### A tibble: 2 x 3
##  product start_date   end_date
##    <dbl>     <date>     <date>
##1       1 2016-01-01 2016-01-10
##2       2 2016-01-03 2016-01-07
```

First, add a column of `ID`s that identifies the rows of the data frame to `group_by` later to determine if there is overlap with any other row. The key is to be able to consider all distinct pairs of rows with the same `product` in testing for overlap. The above code does this by expanding the data as in an *outer-join*. Specifically,

1. Replicate `d` `nrow(d)` times
2. Change the names of the columns by appending `_other` to them so that they can be referenced separately from the original column names in the overlap test
3. Replicate each row of `d` `nrow(d)` times and append the result from (2) as new columns

The result of (3) have rows that enumerates all pairs of rows from the original data frame. Then:

4. Sort them as you did.
5. Consider only pairs where the `product` matches. Do this first to minimize not needed comparisons later
6. Do the overlap test. Here comparison is only made with respect to the previous rows in the original data frame. This has the effect of considering all lags and preserving the row itself (i.e., all rows overlap with itself)
7. Group by the `ID` (each row in original data frame) and keep those for which **all** `overlapping` is `FALSE`

At this point, the result contains only the non-overlapping rows in the original data frame. However, there are all those extra columns, and there are duplicates where multiple rows overlap with a row. The rest of the code cleans that up.

I have tested it with the following data (augmented yours to add a few more test conditions, but far from exhaustive):

```
d <- structure(list(product = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2), start_date = structure(c(16801, 
16802, 16805, 16811, 16962, 16803, 16806), class = "Date"), end_date = structure(c(16810, 
16804, 16961, 16961, 16964, 16807, 16810), class = "Date")), .Names = c("product", 
"start_date", "end_date"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

and got the following results:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  product start_date   end_date
<dbl>     <date>     <date>
1       1 2016-01-01 2016-01-10
2       1 2016-06-10 2016-06-12
3       2 2016-01-03 2016-01-07
```

Hope this helps.