# For each ID, find if dates overlap and then create new dates and remove rows

Tags: r, date, dataframe, dplyr

I have a set of data with ID's and dates.

For each overlapping date, I would like to replace the overlap with the next row (ie. combine the overlapping dates).

NB: There are ID's that have only one row and therefore do not need to be altered. There are those that don't have an overlap and need to remain as they are (ie. with two rows).

Example data:

```
ID Start      End
1  2007-02-01 2007-03-03  
1  2007-03-01 2007-03-31  
1  2007-09-01 2008-07-31  
6  2011-02-05 2011-03-12  
5  2012-11-16 2012-12-26  
4  2015-01-03 2015-02-14  
3  2008-08-02 2008-09-11  
7  2010-09-22 2010-10-22  
7  2010-09-24 2010-10-24  
7  2010-09-26 2010-10-26  
7  2010-09-28 2010-10-28


ID Start      End
1  2007-02-01 2007-03-31  
1  2007-09-01 2008-07-31  
6  2011-02-05 2011-03-12  
5  2012-11-16 2012-12-26  
4  2015-01-03 2015-02-14  
3  2008-08-02 2008-09-11  
7  2010-09-22 2010-10-28
```

Comment: Can you share your data using `dput()`? 
See more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Try `library(dplyr); df1 %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(start = first(start), end = last(end))`

Comment: I have looked at this question here:  
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38617840/how-to-remove-rows-from-a-dataframe-that-have-overlapping-start-and-end-dates-in?rq=1     But these solutions unfortunately don't work for me

Comment: setDT(df)
df.1 <- df[, gr := cumsum(start - shift(end, fill=1) != 1),
   ][, list(start=min(start), end=max(end)), by=.(ID)]

Comment: Solved with solution from @David Arunberg  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28938147/how-to-flatten-merge-overlapping-time-periods-in-r

Answer (score 2):

Based on the example, after grouping by 'ID', we take the `first` of 'start' and `last` of 'end'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   summarise(start = first(start), end = last(end))
```

#### Update

Based on the updated example in the OP's post

```
library(data.table)
df1 %>% 
    mutate_at(2:3, as.Date, format = "%d/%m/%y") %>%
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    group_by(grp = rleid(lead(start, default = last(start)) < end), add = TRUE) %>% 
    summarise(start = first(start), end = last(end)) %>%
    ungroup %>% 
    select(-grp)  %>% 
    mutate_at(2:3, format, format = "%d/%m/%y")
# A tibble: 7 x 3
#     ID start    end     
#  <int> <chr>    <chr>   
#1    84 27/03/09 21/07/17
#2    92 20/04/12 25/01/17
#3   108 12/12/14 25/08/17
#4   111 31/01/14 18/11/16
#5   114 10/04/13 15/07/13
#6   130 05/01/11 04/03/12
#7   130 15/05/12 27/09/13
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(84L, 84L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 108L, 111L, 114L, 
130L, 130L), start = c("27/03/09", "23/02/13", "20/04/12", "18/07/14", 
"5/12/15", "12/12/14", "31/01/14", "10/04/13", "5/01/11", "15/05/12"
), end = c("24/03/13", "21/07/17", "17/08/14", "4/01/16", "25/01/17", 
"25/08/17", "18/11/16", "15/07/13", "4/03/12", "27/09/13")), .Names = c("ID", 
"start", "end"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L
 ))
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. When I run this I get just one start date and one end date.

Comment: Also I am not sure this approach would work for ID's that need to end up with several rows. I have changed my example data above to reflect this option

Comment: thank you @akrun.  When I try your solution I get this error  Error in UseMethod("tbl_vars") : 
  no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "character"

Comment: perhaps the problem is that my ID is a combination of letters and numbers and is in character format

Comment: @sar I tried by converting the 'ID' to character, it is still working.  What is your `dplyr` version?

Comment: yes @akrun, you are right, it does work with character. apologies, it was an error in my transcription of your code

Comment: now i get this error  - Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'grp' not found

Comment: With your example data I get this result     # A tibble: 8 x 3
         ID start      end       
      <int> <chr>      <chr>     
    1    84 NA         NA        
    2    92 NA         NA        
    3    92 NA         04/01/0016
   4    92 05/12/0015 NA        
   5   108 12/12/0014 NA        
   6   111 NA         NA        
   7   114 10/04/0013 NA        
   8   130 05/01/0011 NA

Comment: @sar I don't get any NAs.  what is your dplyr version.  I use `0.7.4`

Comment: thank you @akrun. I found the problems was that I had loaded plyr prior to dplyr. After removing plyr it ran, however, it doesn't actually combine the overlapping rows per ID.

Comment: ID  start    end     
   <chr>       <chr>    <chr>   
4 27/03/09 23/02/13
4 23/02/13 21/07/17
2 20/04/12 05/12/15
2 05/12/15 25/01/17
8 12/12/14 25/08/17
1 31/01/14 18/11/16
7 10/04/13 15/07/13
9 19/03/14 31/07/15
3 27/02/15 20/10/17
10 11/04/14 18/08/17

Comment: Solved! Just needed >=  simple! Thank you @akrun~

Comment: Unfortunately, I thought this was working but it when I have tried it on other sets of data it doesn't work. I will upload some more data as an example

Comment: Solved with a solution from @David Arunberg  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28938147/how-to-flatten-merge-overlapping-time-periods-in-r

Comment: Also the additional comment from @Zachary Keller was also very useful. I needed to use the min and max commands in his solution